# Wampp - I cannot login to phpmyadmin after new installation #2002

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've installed WAMPP server. Apache works correctly, but I cannot login to phpmyadmin. I get this error:

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I have Windows. Mysql is installed with Wampp. I cannot login to mysql from Mysql console (in wampp menu context) I don't know can I set this password.

In config.inc.php I set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourNewpassword';
```

but it doesn't help too.

I think that I have to setup password to mysql because when I installing wamp I didn't get any password. But I don't know how. I try run mysqld.exe in consle - won't to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Windows Event Viewer for messages from MySQL.

The problem here is usually that you have an old my.ini file somewhere. Search for my.ini and if you find one that is NOT in the c:\wamp folder structure ( or whereever you installed it ) then delete them and try starting mysql again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all allow wamp access by changing the firewall settings, or simply click on "allow access" button of firewall warning pop up after a fresh installation.Just After a fresh installation, click on the wampserver icon to run it-> wamp icon will appear on the right side of your taskbar, when you click on this wamp icon->select "start all services".(you will notice a change in its color) again click on wampicon on the taskbar and click-> phpmyAdmin, a login page will appear, you just have to enter the username as "root" and leave the password(no need to enter the password if you are a new user). enter go!!

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd to get a window
Change directory to where mysql console is e.g. C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>

Run the console with mysql

password isn't needed on the default installation and you'll be treated as root

you should get a prompt to enter your password. Use the one you put in your config file.

More info here [MySQL and WAMP](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Setup_MySQL_in_WAMP_-_password_setting,_service_shutdown_&_startup)

PS MysqlD is the mysql daemon, think service in windows terms. mysql and mysqladmin are the console apps to set up and control it.

Comment: I cannot start mysql from console. Now I see that it's not a problem with password

Comment: you can't?. you mean mysql.exe isn't there or it is but won't let you in?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have antivirus software running? If so, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, now I see that the problem is with starting mysql. If I click on Wamp icon -> Mysql -> Service -> Start/Resume service it is turn on several seconds and then it's turn off again. 
When I run mysql from C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin> I get:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

In configuration port is set as 3306.
I think that problem is with starting mysql.

Comment: If the service is stopping, there will be a log file with an error in it. Possibly windows event log as well. You can't connect to it because it isn't there. Log files would normally be under the mysql5.1.36 folder somewhere. PS mysql -P3306 will try to connect to the server on that specific port.